# LEN() formula in Flow Builder not working as expected

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

My formula as seen in the screenshot is not working.

Essentially I'm trying to accomplish "If the length of characters input into this field is greater than 255"

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [validate input](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_screen_validate.htm&type=0) is actually the opposite of a typical validation rule. In this screen, your formula is about denoting whether the input is valid (true) or not (false).

> NOTE
> The formula expression must return a Boolean value (true or false).

> If the formula expression evaluates to true, the input is valid.

> If the formula expression evaluates to false, the error message is displayed to the user.

You should look to be doing the inverse of what you're doing in the formula

```
LEN({!Project_Description}) <= 255
```